# How to generate a random date from a given range with hive

Tags: sql, random, hive, hiveql, date-range

use hive . I need to generate random dates selected from a given date range, between '2019-01-01' and '2019-10-31'. 
Can any one guide me with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `floor(rand*100)%N+1` you can generate random natural numbers in the range 1 .. N. Use lpad to add leading 0 to get two gigits strings like 01, 02 if random number is single digit.

Demo:

```
 select concat('2019','-',lpad(floor(RAND()*100.0)%10+1,2,0),'-',lpad(floor(RAND()*100.0)%31+1,2,0));
```

Result:

```
2019-04-31
```

Add date() function to solve problem with 28, 30 - 31 days in different months. date() will convert invalid date to nearest valid one:
For example date('2019-02-31') returns 2019-03-03

All together:

```
select date(concat('2019','-',lpad(floor(RAND()*100.0)%10+1,2,0),'-',lpad(floor(RAND()*100.0)%31+1,2,0)));
```

Result:

```
2019-07-10
```

**One more option** is to generate required date range with order number and join it with random number:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2019-01-01; 
set hivevar:end_date=2019-10-31; 

with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range with order number, max i=303 for this range 
select date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) as dt, i 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff('${hivevar:end_date}','${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
)

--join range generated with random number 0..303(check max in date_range)
select d.dt from date_range d inner join (select floor(RAND()*100.0)%304 as i) r on d.i=r.i;
```

Result:

```
2019-01-12
```

All tested in Hive.